# PowerDesigner - Assign a TriggerTemplate to a trigger through VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, sybase, datamodel, powerdesigner

In PowerDesigner v12, how would one, through use of VBScript, assign a TriggerTemplate to triggers that are missing the definition?

We have a script now that can loop through the triggers and display the triggertemplate (if it has one), but all attempts to assign a template to these triggers have failed.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Can someone with power edit this and add 'powerdesigner' as a tag?  I can't do it.

Thanks,
Calvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found an answer, but I want to get other input on it.

While I cannot get a reference to the TriggerTemplates that are part of the DBMS, the model itself can have its own TriggerTemplates.  These model based templates can be referenced and assigned to the triggers as needed.

My thoughts were to actually create copies of the DBMS templates inside the model, and use those instead.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you use `model.DBMS.TriggerTemplates`?