# How to create a Trigger and assign a TriggerTemplate using PowerDesigner VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, powerdesigner

I'm using PowerDesigner v16 and I created an `Extension`; in this `Extension` a `MetaClass` of the Table type was added; in this `MetaClass` an Event Handler was created, using VBScript, to go through all the tables and create some fields / columns (attributes) default in all tables.

But now I want to take advantage of that I'm going through all the tables and also through `VBScript` to create a standard `Trigger` that is in `TriggerTemplate`, and I don´t know how to do this through VBScript.

My main question is: how to create a `Trigger` using `VBScript` and assign a `TriggerTemplate`?

Can you provide me with an example?

Possibly related question:

- [PowerDesigner - Assign a TriggerTemplate to a trigger through VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928637/powerdesigner-assign-a-triggertemplate-to-a-trigger-through-vbscript)
- **Below is the function I use to go through the entire table and check if there are standard columns:**

Note: This function is performed in a `PowerDesigner` `Extencion` using PDM modeling. And the path of this extension is as follows: `DEFAULT COLUMNS::Profile\Table\Event Handlers\Initialize`

```
'******************************************************************************
' Função para checar se a coluna já existe na tabela.
'******************************************************************************
function ColumnExists(tab, name)
   'output "ClassName: " + tab.ClassName
   
   'Checa se a o objeto passano no parâmetro "tab" é do tipo Table (tabela)
   if tab.ClassName = "Table" then
      dim col
      'Passa por todas as colunas da tabela
      for each col in tab.Columns
         'Checa se o nome da coluna atual já existe igual ao passado por parâmetro ("name")
         if col.Name = name then
            'output "... já existe " + col.Name
            ColumnExists = true
            exit function
         end if
      next 
   end if
   ColumnExists = false
end function

'******************************************************************************
' Função responsável por criar as colunas padrao de uma tabela.
'******************************************************************************
Sub DoCreateColumns(tab)
   
   ' Checa se o objeto passado no parâmetro ("tab") é do tipo "Table"
   if not tab.ClassName = "Table" then exit sub
   dim c
   dim myColumns, column

 
   ' Executa função "DefaultColumns()" serve para criar um array com todas as colunas padrão
   myColumns = DefaultColumns()
   
   'Passa por todas as colunas salvas'
   for each column in myColumns
       
       'Checa se esta coluna é um ID
       if column.Name = "ID_" then
            ' Adiciona o nome da tabela junto com a palavra ID
            column.Name = "ID_" + tab.Name
            column.Code = column.Name
       end if
       
       'Checa se a coluna ja existe
       if not ColumnExists(tab, column.Name) then
           set c = tab.Columns.CreateNewAt(column.Position) 
           c.Name = column.Name
           c.Code = column.Code
           c.domain = column.Domain
           c.Mandatory = column.Mandatory
           output "... adding column " + column.Name + " table " + tab.Name
       end if
   next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a SAP SQL Anywhere 17 PDM with one table, saved it as a .pdm file; then added a trigger based on a template on this table, and saved the model as a new .pdm file. By comparing the files, I get some hints of the representation of triggers + templates.

Especially that the trigger template is attached to the trigger. Through a shortcut, as the template is in the DBMS while the trigger is in the model.

```
<o:Table Id="o9">
    <a:Name>Table_1</a:Name>
    <a:Code>TABLE_1</a:Code>
    <c:Triggers>
        <o:Trigger Id="o10">
            <a:Name>Trigger_1</a:Name>
            <a:Code>TRIGGER_1</a:Code>
            <c:BaseTrigger.TriggerItems>
                <o:Shortcut Ref="o5"/>
                <o:Shortcut Ref="o6"/>
            </c:BaseTrigger.TriggerItems>
            <c:TriggerTemplate>             <===
                <o:Shortcut Ref="o4"/>      <===
            </c:TriggerTemplate>
        </o:Trigger>
    </c:Triggers>
```

Looking at the help file `SAP PowerDesigner 16 OLE Help`, I see the TriggerTemplate as a property of the `BaseTrigger` class, from which `Trigger` is derived.

Here is an example which uses that.

```
option explicit
' create model
dim mdl : set mdl = CreateModel(PDPdm.cls_PdmModel, "|DBMS=SAP SQL Anywhere 17")
' create table and trigger
dim tbl : set tbl = mdl.CreateObject(PDPdm.cls_Table)
dim trig : set trig = tbl.CreateObject(PDPdm.cls_Trigger)
' set trigger template
SetTemplate trig, "BeforeUpdateTrigger"

function SetTemplate(trg, typ)
   SetTemplate = false
   ' find template
   dim db : set db = trg.Model.DBMS
   ' in case of shared DBMS instead of embedded one
   if db.IsShortcut() then set db = db.TargetObject
   dim tm, found
   for each tm in db.TriggerTemplates
      if tm.name = typ then
         set found = tm
         exit for
      end if
   next
   if IsEmpty(found) then exit function
   ' create shortcut alongside the table
   dim fld : set fld = trg.Parent.Folder
   dim short : set short = found.CreateShortcut(fld)
   ' assign, and initialize
   set trg.TriggerTemplate = short
   trg.InitFromTemplate
   SetTemplate = true
end function
```

Comment: I could not understand the example.
You can detail the example, or even add images.

Please.

Comment: I've added an example.